# Python: Unexpected area results after converting lat/long coordinates to wkid:3857

Tags: arcgis-server, pyproj, arcgis-python-api

My end-goal is to be able to calculate the areas of small polygons (between 1000 and 5000 sq ft) with lat/long coordinates. I am having some unexpected results when doing this and decided to switch to a more uniform and larger area (a high-school football field).

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.geometry import lengths, areas_and_lengths, project
from arcgis.geometry import Point, Polygon, Polyline, Geometry
from pyproj import Proj, transform

# define the original polygon (the corners of a high-school football field)
my_polygon = Polygon({'spatialReference': {'wkid': 4326}, 
            'rings': [[[-97.73274828462698, 30.284176038755415], 
                       [-97.73224604100734, 30.284137821762556], 
                       [-97.73234528273382, 30.283154018580472], 
                       [-97.73284886747372, 30.283192815006274], 
                       [-97.73274828462698, 30.284176038755415]]]})


# convert from '4326' to '3857'
new_coords = []
original = Proj(init='EPSG:4326') # EPSG:4326 in your case
destination = Proj(init='EPSG:3857') # your new EPSG

for ring in my_polygon['rings'][0]:
    long, lat = ring
    x,y = transform(original, destination, long, lat)
    new_coords.append([x,y])
    
polygon1_reprojected = Polygon({'spatialReference': {'latestWkid': 3857}, 
                'rings': [new_coords]
                })

polygon1_reprojected.area
```

This results in -7174.81640625, but we expect ~4,500... Why?

Comment: Do they really have football fields in Antarctica? Speaking of Antarctica, that's where the area [distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Distortion_of_sizes) is at its maximum...  --> fix the coordinate order and never ever compute any distance or area in 3857

Comment: @JGH I had the coordinates reversed. I fixed that. Thank you, sir